# Why am I getting 2 types of web pages (design-wise) on ELU?

Tags: support

I am getting 2 types of web pages for ELU on my android phone(s), one of which seems like the desktop version (see first image below) and the other looks like a mobile version (second image)

[image]

[image]

The 2 types of pages have distinctly different design especially with color scheme but also other features, and the first type of page (beige colored) has small fonts and is generally difficult to read on smaller android phones.

Is this typical? If not, how can I get my phone to always display the second type of page, which has larger fonts and is generally more legible for smaller screens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technical term for this situation is that your styles got 'discombobulated'.

Click on the 'mobile' link below to get the styling intended for a phone.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and useful reply!

Comment: I don't really know 'why' that happens. I just knew about a fix for it, having had something similar happen to me a few times.

Comment: +1 [Discombobulate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLuhWLNqpiA)

Comment: A good fix indeed,  which worked for me!

Comment: Not every page has a mobile version; if you navigate to one of those you get stuck in "desktop" mode even if you go to a page that has a mobile version afterwards.